# bundle product not open

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, bundle-product

I just Migrated Mganeto 1.9.* to 2.3.0. All set well but when I open Bundle product that throws an error: This product doesn't exist.
And in log, I got

> :[2019-03-13 09:16:16] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'option_value_default.parent_product_id' in
>   'on clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*,
>   `option_value_default`.`title` AS `default_title`,
>   IF(option_value.title IS NOT NULL, option_value.title,
>   option_value_default.title) AS `title` FROM
>   `catalog_product_bundle_option` AS `main_table`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON cpe.entity_id =
>   main_table.parent_id  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`
>   AS `option_value_default` ON main_table.option_id =
>   option_value_default.option_id AND main_table.parent_id =
>   option_value_default.parent_product_id AND
>   option_value_default.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` AS `option_value` ON
>   main_table.option_id = option_value.option_id AND main_table.parent_id
>   = option_value.parent_product_id AND option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (cpe.entity_id = '18950') ORDER BY `main_table`.`position` asc,
>   `main_table`.`option_id` asc  {"exception":"[object]
>   (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'option_value_default.parent_product_id' in
>   'on clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*,
>   `option_value_default`.`title` AS `default_title`,
>   IF(option_value.title IS NOT NULL, option_value.title,
>   option_value_default.title) AS `title` FROM
>   `catalog_product_bundle_option` AS `main_table`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON cpe.entity_id =
>   main_table.parent_id  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`
>   AS `option_value_default` ON main_table.option_id =
>   option_value_default.option_id AND main_table.parent_id =
>   option_value_default.parent_product_id AND
>   option_value_default.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` AS `option_value` ON
>   main_table.option_id = option_value.option_id AND main_table.parent_id
>   = option_value.parent_product_id AND option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (cpe.entity_id = '18950') ORDER BY `main_table`.`position` asc,
>   `main_table`.`option_id` asc

Then I wont to create a new bundle product for testing at that time I got another

> error:Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException):
>   The "formElement" configuration parameter is required for the
>   "price_type" field.